# Checking the length of a stream

Tags: vb.net, ftp, stream, filestream

So i have written code to allow me to download files from an FTP server using the system.io.stream function in vb.net. Now I need to be able to find the length of the stream, when i has finished.

I have worked with streamreader in the past but this stream doesn't work in the same way so i'm not sure how to proceed.

```
 Try
    Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest
    request = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.server.com/Folder/" & FileName & ".pdf"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password")
    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
    'Dim OutPutFilepath As String = "DownloadTest" & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName("ftp://ftp.Server.com/Folder/")
    output = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\TestFile2.pdf")
    output.Close()
    stream.Close()
    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded")
    Console.ReadLine()


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Also, I have tried using the stream.length feature however, i got an exception saying something along the lines of "this stream does not support seek functions".

Thanks in advance

Comment: wouldn't the size of the created file give you that info?  If a stream does not support seeking, length and position will throw that exception

Comment: i need to constantly check the size as it downloads so i can see the percentage downloaded.

Comment: I think you want `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize` for the total/length

Comment: What about the file size as it downloads

Comment: the file size doesnt change as it downloads, only the number of bytes you have received.

Comment: You are getting the file in a single call so you cannot check the size as it downloads. To do that, you will have to research downloading the file in chunks which is the better way to go if they could be large files.